# Why is my CSS code to center the logo not working?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I think .custom-logo class is as specific as it gets for the logo image. But even whilst using !important, the logo is not only not aligning how I want it to, also the inspector is still showing the margin-left: 650px; that I used previously to adjust the position of the logo (this was only meant to be temporary until I would have figured out how to align it properly, which I didnt). See CSS Code, HTML code and the picture of my website:

```
.custom-logo {
width: 350px;
height: 350px;
margin-left: auto !important;
margin-right:auto !important;
display:block;
```

}

```
<img width="719" height="719" src="http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cropped-logomatmart2.png" class="custom-logo" alt="<-MattmArt->" itemprop="logo" srcset="http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cropped-logomatmart2.png 719w, http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cropped-logomatmart2-150x150.png 150w, http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cropped-logomatmart2-300x300.png 300w, http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cropped-logomatmart2-100x100.png 100w" sizes="(max-width: 719px) 100vw, 719px">
```

[Picture of my child-css style sheet and the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl3uK.jpg)

Comment: It sounds like your styles are not getting updated. Try hitting `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `R`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your CSS shows that .logo has margin-left: auto; and your dev tools show that the style still holds an old value the problem lies within your cache.

Since you are using wordpress you probably have a cache plugin. You will need to clear the cache from the plugin, then clear the cache from the browser.

If you are using a CDN like cloudflare you may need to clear that cache as well.

Also note that some hosts like SiteGround have some very strong caching built into their servers so you may need to clear that out as well.

Sometimes you can view the page in incognito mode or use a different browser.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your local, and hard refreshing if it has old styles still applied.